# Find a value from list based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I am having two dataset data1 and data2
in data1 columns are lat long locationid1 and countrycode
in data2 columns are lat long locationid2.
I wrote code like
if locationid2!=None and len(locationid2)>0 and str(locationid2)!='nan' and locationid2 in list(data["locationid1"]):
macth={True}

but here I want to add countrycode in matching.like..if locationid1 having coluntrycode="GB" then only it is go for matching with locationid2
data1

[image]
[image]

Expected output

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post there small input dataframe and expected output? (with correct formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
ids = data1.loc[data1["countrycode"].eq("GB"), "locationid1"]
data2["match"] = np.where(data2["locationid2"].isin(ids), "TRUE", "FALSE")
print(data2)
```

Prints:

```
   lat  long  locationid2  match
0    6    42          111  FALSE
1    7    43          112  FALSE
2    8    44          113   TRUE
3    9    45          114   TRUE
4   10    46          115  FALSE
```